# How to compare string in MongoDB whether it is in lowercase or is in uppercase

Tags: node.js, regex, mongodb, express, mongodb-query

I am working on a MERN project and on User Login I am finding that user like this :

User.findOne({username:req.body.username}).exec(function(err,user){
if(user){
Lines of code....
});

Imagine my username is Imran saved in Db and send username in the above code as .

Case1:
req.body.username = Imran
User Found 
1

Case2:
req.body.username = imran
User Found 
0

Case3:
req.body.username = imRan
User Found
0

If I use regex to find username like this...

User.findOne({username: {$regex: username , $options : "i"}})

It will find user in all above case but if I type imr rather than Imran or imran or imRan with password given it will login that user again which is not correct ! So I am hoping. If someone could help me with the matter ! That'll be great !

Comment: Could you please explain what do you wish to do with the username field ?  AFAIK, the mongodb would validate your username only for Case 1 and this should be the only case. If you are intending to perform auto complete or any other actions, then its better to have it done in the top layers rather than your db to minimize your burden over performance.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend to store lowercase usernames at least you want to differentiate lower and upper case usernames, if that the case,  `Imran` and `imran` are two different users. Either way, to match case-insensitive query, you could try this:

```
User.findOne({username: /^imran$/i})
```

Or

```
User.findOne({username: {$regex: '^imran$', $options: 'i'}})
```

In the last one you pass the regex value as string so you can include a variable between `^` and `$`, hope this helps.

Comment: How can I give a dynamic value other than Imran ! I am doing  like this .. User.findOne( {username: /^username$/I } )... But isn't working

Comment: try with: `User.findOne({username: {$regex: '^imran$', $options: 'i'}})`, I'll edit

Comment: You make it dynamic by using the variable ```User.findOne({username: {$regex: new RegExp(`^${username}$`, 'i')}})```

Comment: Note that `imran.munawar@gmail.com` and `imranamunawar@gmail.com` match when using either \b\b or ^$ since the dot is interpreted as any string.

Answer (score 1):

You would want to normalize the data when you save it by calling `username.toLowerCase()` (or `toUpperCase()`). Then, when you perform the query, you would call `User.findOne({username:req.body.username.toLowerCase()})`

Comment: I second this suggestion. It's generally bad practice to not sanitize user input and store them directly in your database. Unless you intend to allow mixed-case username, you should sanitize your inputs.

Comment: I dont fully agree. What if the casing is actually important? Like on names? Why would you save data lowercased?

Comment: @JuanManuelHaedo you would definitely only want to normalize the data in this fashion if casing is not important. For example, email addresses are case-insensitive. For case-sensitive fields, you would need to use a case-insensitive $regex search, or you could have a duplicated field that's normalized to all lower case for case insensitive searches.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for the help ! I have found the solution that works for me .
User.findOne( { username: new RegExp("\b" + username + "\b" , "i" ) } ....
This will match the username string whether if it is in lowercase or in uppercase . Hope it helps you :)

Comment: As per my comment above, this won't work for the same reason (regex inside string interferes).

Answer (score 0):

In my use case (emails) I had issues as the other answers would match data that was not escaped.

For example, when using unescaped strings, the . (dot character) in emails would be used to match any character, and thus `imran.munawar@gmail.com` and `imranamunawar@gmail.com` would both match when searching for `imran.munawar@gmail.com`.

My solution to this was to escape the string first. I also recommend sanitising your inputs, but if you cannot, make sure you escape your strings.

```
    if (email) {
        email = _.escapeRegExp(email.toLowerCase());
        let filter = { email: { $regex: new RegExp(`^${email}$`, 'i') } };
    }
```

The above solution requires [lodash](https://lodash.com/) but can be done with a string replacement method instead.